# How can I tell if a user is blocked?

Tags: skype, privacy

I have recently had to **remove and block** a contact from Skype (Skype 8, Windows 10).
Now, as is supposed to be they are no longer in my contacts list. Good.

However, I don't remember if I actually blocked them or not.

I can still find their profile (Through search for 'add contact'), and at the bottom is says 'Block contact'. This, however, always stays the same... Never even changing to something like 'unblock'.

I also **deleted** all history with this person.

Is it still possible for them to contact me? Is there any way for me to tell if they are actually blocked? As they are **no longer a contact**?

(This problem seems consistent throughout all editions of the application I have access to: Skype 8 for windows 10, Android, and Online)

Comment: A blocked Skype contact is unable to send you messages

Comment: @Ramhound So I have to ask them to try to send me a message to ensure they are blocked? Seems counterproductive.

Comment: If you blocked them, then they are blocked, they stay blocked until you block them. If you want to see a list of blocked contacts [Skype](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/fa34809/how-do-i-block-unblock-or-report-someone-in-skype) has you convered.

Comment: @Ramhound That's my problem: I want to see people who are blocked who *aren't* contacts. I deleted the contact, then went into their profile to block them. I cannot tell if it actually worked.